# Google App Engine - App worked on local GAE Dev Server, but failed on GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, cxf, gae-whitelist

Today I uploaded my app for the first time, and it failed when the first request came in to trigger the app to initialize. I've tested everything locally on Google GAE DEV server, is there any difference between Google DEV server and the realy GAE environment?

I kind of understand that it might be caused by GAE security restrictions, but the app works fine on local GAE Dev server though.

Below is the exception:

> Failed startup of context org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletTransportFactory' defined in class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (2) are:
>   PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'bus' threw exception; nested exception is java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission getClassLoader)
>   PropertyAccessException 2: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'transportIds' threw exception; nested exception is java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission getClassLoader)

Comment: We can't possibly figure out what the problem is without more details. When is the exception thrown? What is the code in question?

Comment: Please paste the (complete!) stacktrace as a code block, so formatting isn't destroyed, and include the relevant bit of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [it works on my machine](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/the-works-on-my-machine-certification-program.html). :)
Sorry for not being much help, but I suspect that you're using something that is not on the [gae-whitelist](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist.html).
See this article about [cxf on gae](http://sinister2010.wordpress.com/2010/01/22/cxf-rs-on-google-app-engine-exposed3/).